# Mathematica numerical "error" for simple multiplication

Tags: numerics, syntax

[image: The result seems weird for simple multiplication, I have no idea why this happens.]

```
In[71]:= 0.6*0.8048780487804877`

Out[71]= 0.482927

In[72]:= 0.3*0.8414634146341463`

Out[72]= 0.252439

In[74]:= (0.6*0.8048780487804877`) + 0.3*0.8414634146341463`

Out[74]= 0.735366

In[75]:= 0.6*0.8048780487804877`+0.3*0.8414634146341463`

Out[75]= 0.406365
```

Why the brackets In[74] and In[75] have effect? I think it should have no difference.
I use mathematica 12.1.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is definitely one of Mathematica's "gotchas." This lexical quirk is a consequence of Wolfram Language allowing both a plus and a minus in the number in a precision annotation. Since the precision annotation is infix instead of matchfix, there is no good way of avoiding some version of this lexical trap, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `In[75]` is completely different than you think.

```
0.6*0.8048780487804877`+0.3*0.8414634146341463`
(* 0.406365 *)

0.6*0.8048780487804877` + 0.3*0.8414634146341463`
(* 0.735366 *)
```

Notice the space in the second example: in your case `+0.3` is a specification for precision for tick [`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberMarks.html)

Easier example:

```
(* in this case it's specification of precision *)
1.2`+30
(* 1.20000000000000000000000000000 *)

(* in this case it's 1.2 with $MachinePrecision, plus 30 *)
1.2` + 30
(* 31.2 *)
```

Comment: "arbitrary-precision" It's `$MachinePrecision` when a precision isn't specified after the tick.

Comment: @RobertJacobson Nope, it's `MachinePrecision`. Indeed, there is a difference! Compare `N[1, MachinePrecision]` and `N[1, $MachinePrecision]`.

Comment: You are right! Now I need to go edit my other comment!

Comment: N.B. Once upon a time, `N[1, $MachinePrecision]` was used to get a machine precision result. Version 5 introduced `MachinePrecision`, so that `N[1, MachinePrecision]` was what you now had to do to get a machine precision result, and `N[1, $MachinePrecision]` now produced an arbitrary precision result. Perhaps this is what @Robert was (mis)remembering.

Answer (score 8):

`` 0.8048780487804877`+0.3 `` is an arbitrary-precision number with precision `0.3`.

With the parentheses, the `0.3` does not specify the precision, but stands as a number.  The second line is equivalent to

```
0.6 * (0.8048780487804877`+0.3) * 0.8414634146341463`
```

Comment: Note that 3.0 will be a `$MachinePrecision` number.

Comment: @RobertJacobson I suppose you meant `0.3`, not `3.0`. Do you mean `$MachinePrecision` (i.e., arbitrary precision) or `MachinePrecision` number?  Do you just mean that the precision of an arbitrary-precision number is specified by a `MachinePrecision` number?

Comment: The value of `MachinePrecision` is `$MachinePrecision`. Real numbers with fewer than `$MachinePrecision` digits have precision `$MachinePrecision`.

Comment: (Technically, `MachinePrecision` is `n*Log[10, 2]` where `n` is the IEEE mantissa on the host system, and `$MachinePrecision` is the `MachinePrecision` approximation to `MachinePrecision`.)

Comment: I see that I am confused! Your question is spot on. As @Henrik points out below, there *is* a difference between `MachinePrecision` and `$MachinePrecision`. Good grief. (Do I delete my incorrect comment? What's the protocol?)

Comment: Just to clarify: Arbitrary precision numbers (aka "bignums") can have precision less than $MachinePrecision.

Answer (score 4):

It's not hte parentheses; it's the missing whitespace!

There is a tiny difference between the meanings of

```
 0.8048780487804877`+0.3
```

> 0.*10^-1

and

```
 0.8048780487804877` +0.3
```

> 1.10488

We have

```
 0.8048780487804877`+0.3 == 0.8048780487804877`0.3
```

and the number behind the backtick denotes the number of significant digits. In particular, no addition is performed during evaluation of in case of `` 0.8048780487804877`+0.3 ``

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can raise all the numbers to a higher precision:

```
0.6`50 0.8048780487804877`50 + 0.3`50*0.8414634146341463`50
(*0.7353658536585365100000000000000000000000000000000*)
```